# how to update an inner record in elm

Tags: elm

I have this model

```
type alias Model = 
  { exampleId : Int
  , groupOfExamples : GroupExamples
  }

type alias GroupExamples = 
  { groupId : Int
  , results : List String
  }
```

In my update function, if I want to update the exampleId would be like this:

```
 { model | exampleId = updatedValue }
```

But what if I need to do to update, for example, just the results value inside of GroupExamples?

Comment: https://github.com/evancz/focus - when you have nested datastructures

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way to do it in the language without anything extra is to destructure the outer record like:

```elm
let
    examples = model.groupOfExamples
    newExamples = { examples | results = [ "whatever" ] }
in
    { model | groupOfExamples = newExamples }
```

There is also the [focus package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/focus/latest) which would allow you to:

```elm
set ( groupOfExamples => results ) [ "whatever" ] model
```