# elm - updating a record within a record

Tags: updates, record, elm

What is the correct/best way to update a record within a record?

The following attempt:

```
type alias Model =
  { pageView : PageView
  , landingPageModel : Dict
  }

--update
update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
   ChangePage pView ->
     { model | pageView = pView }
   PostCode pCode ->
     let
       lPModel =
         model.landingPageModel
       newlPModel =
         { lPModel |  postCode = pCode }
     in
      { model | landingPageModel = newlPModel }
```

gave this error:

```
The type annotation for `update` does not match its definition.

19│ update : Action -> Model -> Model
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type annotation is saying:

    Action
    -> { ..., landingPageModel : Dict }
    -> { ..., landingPageModel : Dict }

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

    Action
    -> { ..., landingPageModel : { a | postCode : String } }
    -> { ..., landingPageModel : { a | postCode : String } }
```

This is somewhat surprising - isn't a literal `Dict` update of type `Dict`?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with dictionaries, please edit it.

Comment: thanks, that's been done

Comment: This is Elm's 'lens' library, but note the health warnings - I've never used it in practise http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/focus/2.0.0/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update an inner record in elm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958667/how-to-update-an-inner-record-in-elm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to expand the `Model` definition :

```
type alias Model =
  { pageView : PageView
  , landingPageModel : { postCode : String }
  }
```

Also, as per halfzebra's comment, Dict's have no relevance here - just records.